# Chef resource yum_package not working as expected

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to use the following code block to install an rpm I have inside a custom Artifactory repo:

```
yum_package 'apache-activemq-5.14.3-1.x86_64' do
  package_name 'apache-activemq-5.14.3-1.x86_64'
  action :install
end
```

This ends the chef run in an error:

```
   * yum_package[apache-activemq-5.14.3-1.x86_64] action install[2017-03-01T16:46:05-05:00] INFO: Processing yum_package[apache-activemq-5.14.3-1.x86_64] action install (cookbook::activemq line 91)

     * No candidate version available for apache-activemq-5.14.3-1.x86_64
     ================================================================================
     Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[apache-activemq-5.14.3-1.x86_64]'
```

This rpm installs via commandline with yum with no special needs however:

```
yum install apache-activemq-5.14.3-1.x86_64
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is this:

```
package 'apache-activemq' do
  version '5.14.3-1'
end
```

You can use the `package` resource since yum is already the default for platforms where it is used, and you use the `version` property to specify which version to install.

Comment: Thanks! not sure why I was thinking I'd need yum_package :)